# Join 2 select queries into one php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

there are a lot of similar questions out there but after trying for a little over an hour I was unable to use any of those answers to accomplish my task.

I have 2 separate databases for 2 different gaming servers. We will call these databases DB1 and DB2. I am trying to select all the information from the 'ban' table in each database, and merge them into one PHP variable so that I can display them. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could do this.

I have already tried doing this with a SQL JOIN query like the one bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.bans JOIN DB2.bans
```

And one like this that I found on here:

```
SELECT * FROM ugwebhost_buildrpnew.bans UNION SELECT * FROM ugwebhost_SemiRpNew.bans
```

I am looking to either find a query that will return all the data from both. Or use 2 different queries and the just merge the results into one PHP variable.

Comment: Can we see the DB structure of each? Like column names?

Comment: Column names. steamid, name, admin, reason, time, banned

Answer (score 0):

Exist a Linked Server between DB1 and DB2?

Comment: Yes they are on the same server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run the same query against two different databases - not using the same connection object at least. You'll have to run each query once for every DB. Then you can use a structure like a Set to store results from both queries and eliminate duplicates at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html. I have never used this myself, but it seems this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT item1, item2, item3 FROM DB1.bans 
UNION 
SELECT item1, item2, item3 FROM DB2.bans
```